# high availability database ( postgresql ) with docker swarm

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, devops, docker-swarm

i am new to docker, and just learning docker for quite sometimes,for i am working with LAPP ( Linux, Apache, PHP and PostreSQL ) stack and always working with monolithic architecture where all the things are put together into one single server / vps.

after i learn about docker my mind changes quite a bit, and now i am going to try how to containerized the stack. When i came into the db, i thought if i implemented docker in swarm mode, the db can replicated or sync automatically in my worker node when i scale it up.. but in fact it does not. And here is my .yml file i am using to re-produce the scenario.

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mydocker_pass
      POSTGRES_USER: mydocker_user
      POSTGRES_DB: mydocker
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  db-data:
```

at the first time i just create a single container inside my `swarm-manager` but then i scale up this service with this command `docker service scale db_stack_db=2` it works perfectly, now new container are running in my worker node. In my `worker` node i also have the same volume which i already have in my `manager` node but sadly when i write something into the `db` in the `manager` node, it doesn't show up in my `worker` node and vice versa though they have the same volume name, and pre-created database : `mydocker` and also have the same db user : `mydocker_user` and db_password `mydocker_password` which means instance in `worker` node are not syncing with `manager` node.

then if anyone here is experienced this kind of scenario, please help me and please kindly share your thoughts with me, what is the best practice with swarm mode? do i only have to put one node for db, because if i scale the db up and if it running in the `worker` node is it useful and helping the load of the db service? since it doesn't have same data between `manager` and `worker` node.

regards.

Comment: Are you trying to run two PostgreSQL servers against the same data directory? Cease and desist! Databases have persistent state, which makes them special and difficult to integrate into a world of scaling by cloning.

Comment: i think you got the point but i don't know what i described above is the same as what you just mention, and let's say it's right just as what you just said.. then can you suggest what is better approach for the LAPP stack if i still want to implement docker-swarm, which service should i scale then it can work in the `worker` node?

Comment: I don't know anything about docker swarms, so maybe somebody else can give you better advice. It is difficult to impossible to scale databases horizontally. Typically, you are best off with a single beefy machine/VM/container to handle all the load. Other, similarly beefy databases are configured as "streaming replication standby" (a shared-nothing architecture) and a cluster software like Patroni can fail over between these databases.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thank you, although i haven't get the answer yet, your suggestion of share nothing architecture will be useful..

Comment: You should look up information about data replication in PostgreSQL. Just spinning up two instances with the same volume won't work. There is a lot of useful information about this topic. Also, keep in mind that you probably will run into a lot of issues that will be hard to resolve. Especially with persitant storage for your database cluster. Been there, done that. Now I run my DB clusters outside Docker, much more stable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you Odyssee, i will try to look deeper into PostgreSql, but i just feel curios then if this kind of approach ( swarm mode ) seems like does not help much..it seems like.. may be because i am just new to docker and swarm and does not see the advantages yet..

Comment: This is a bit of an old question, but we’re you able to figure out the problem? Reading through it, it sounds like you might have had the two database instances on different nodes. However, like @LaurenzAlbe said you defined don’t want to have two db instances running at a time. The data will be corrupted very, very fast.